# Why do Rmd change global variables (default)?

Tags: r, variables, r-markdown

I never expected the following bahavior:

Save the following Rmd in `/folder` as `testi.Rmd`

````
---
title: "testi"
author: ""
date: "29 November 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r}
i <- 15
```
````

Then run the following script

```
i <- 0
print(i)
rmarkdown::render("folder/testi.Rmd", encoding = "UTF-8", quiet = TRUE)
print(i)
```

In the end, `i` is set to `15` because of the chunk in the Rmd? It took quite some time to figure that out. Is that intended? What is the use case here which allows "rendering" variables to change? I could not find anything in the web or in `?rmarkdown::render`

Comment: This behaviour is from the side of the R language, rather than from the Rmarkdown side. Put your code in a Rscript, source it, and you can still change the variable `i` in the current workspace.

Comment: This is different from a bash script where calling a subscript in your master script will invoke an individual subprocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `envir` argument. Run the following script to see

```
i <- 0
print(i)
rmarkdown::render("folder/testi.Rmd", encoding = "UTF-8", quiet = TRUE, envir=new.env())
print(i)
```

Comment: That's true. But why is that not the default? Rendering means to me the same as e.g. `print` and I would not expect that `print` may change anything in the environment - it should just print something!

Comment: If you use the RStudio IDE, the default behavior of the knit button is to render in a new empty environment. It is useful to be able to specify the environment on which you want to evaluate something. Unfortunately, I can't say why the default is not to use an empty environment, that would make more sense for me too honestly...